# GORM domain variable without belongsto

Tags: grails, groovy, orm, grails-orm

What is the different in GORM between

```
class Books {
  Author author
}
```

and

```
class Books {
   static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}
```

Does cascading rules changes in these two approaches? Also, when to use `belongsTo` and more importantly, when not to use `belongsTo` in Grails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `belongsTo` is intended for controlling cascades of saves and deletes.  You may reference the full documentation here http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html but to summarize (and in case the URL dies someday):

- Use `belongsTo` to indicate ownership.  Saves or deletes to the parent will cascade to the child.  In your example, if the `Author` is deleted, his `Books` will be too (assuming `Author hasMany Books`
- Do not use `belongsTo` if you just want to indicate a relationship with no ownership on either side and no automatic cascading of saves or deletes.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure about the cascading rules. :)